# I need to loop through html in elements in ejs file to check for errors

Tags: node.js, express

This is my ejs file. I'm basically creating a authentication app with express JS. I need to loop through the Name, Username, Email and password and if it's empty, I want to print out an error message. This is the ejs file:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Account Registration</h1>
    </div>

    <% if(error) { %>

    <% for(var i = 0; i (dunno what to do here) %>

    <% } %>

    <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
        <div class="database">

            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">

            <label id="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">

            <label id="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">

            <label id="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">

            <label id="password2">Confrm Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Conform Password"><br>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-4">Submit</button>

        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

And this is the router.post file for register.ejs

```js
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login');
});

//post register
router.post('register', function(req, res) {
    var name= req.body.name;
    var username= req.body.username;
    var email= req.body.email;
    var password= req.body.password;
    var password2= req.body.password2;

//Validating
    checkBody('name', "Name is required").notEmpty();
    checkBody('username', "Username is required").notEmpty();
    checkBody('email', "Email is required").notEmpty();
    checkBody('email', "Email is in wrong format").isEmail();
    checkBody('password', "Password is required").notEmpty();
    checkBody('password2', "Passwords did not match").isEqual(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('register', {errors:errors})
    }else{
        var newUser = User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password
        });

    }
});
```

I'm new in express js. Would appreciate some help.Thank you. Hope you understood my problem,

Comment: What code is inside `checkBody(...)`? And what issues are you facing with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through all errors and display them using `ul` and `li` tag like this

```
<% if (errors.length > 0) { %>
        <ul>
            <% for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) { %>
               <li><%= errors[i].msg %></li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
<% } %>
```

Comment: `{{#if errors}}
      {{#each errors}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{msg}}</div>
      {{/each}}
{{/if}}
`

I just need these hbs code converted into ejs